# Segmentation Fault when shutting down Linux with assembly application

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, gnu, shutdown

The following application generates a *Segmentation Fault* when executed:

```
.set __NR_reboot, 169
.set LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, 0x4321FEDC

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
   movl $LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, %ebx
   movl $__NR_reboot, %eax
   int $0x80
```

It's a quite simple application and I must be missing something really obvious. Can someone help me?

It was compiled with:

```
as shutdown.s -o shutdown.o
ld shutdown.o -o shutdown
```

**EDIT:**

Even a simple application that just calls syscall sync() generates a *Segmentation Fault*:

```
.set __NR_sync, 36

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
   movl $__NR_sync, %eax
   int $0x80

   movl $1, %eax         #syscall exit
   movl $0, %eax
   int $0x80
```

Comment: Shouln't the second `movl` be to `%ebx`?

Comment: @user786653 Perfect. Add it as an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WARNING**: remember to `sync(2)` before calling `reboot(2)`.

The [`reboot(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/reboot.2.html) system call takes 4 parameters.You are confusing it with the libc 
wrapper.

**WARNING**: remember to `sync(2)` before calling `reboot(2)`.

(It actually takes the *magic** parameters so that people have to reread the documentation and don't forget calling `sync(2)`.)

**WARNING**: Did I say that you have to `sync(2)` before calling `reboot(2)`?

Comment: This *sync* answer gets *SYNC* better every **sync** time **SYNC** I read **Remember to SYNC!** it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding the **final & working source code** as this question might interest somebody in the future:

```
                                     # For the right sys_call numbers on your arch,
                                     # check <asm/unistd_32.h> (or unistd_64.h)

.set __NR_sync, 36                   # sys_call sync()    
.set __NR_reboot, 88                 # sys_call reboot()

.set LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, 0xfee1dead # flags are specified in: <linux/reboot.h>
.set LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, 672274793
.set LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF, 0x4321fedc
.set LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART, 0x01234567

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
   movl $__NR_sync, %eax             # call sync()
   int $0x80

   movl $__NR_reboot, %eax
   movl $LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1, %ebx
   movl $LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2, %ecx
   movl $LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_RESTART, %edx
   #movl $0, %esi
   int $0x80                         # call reboot()

   movl $1, %eax
   movl $0, %ebx
   int $0x80                         # call exit()
```

Comment: Of course, this code needs to be executed by **root** to work. If a regular user tries to execute it the program will fail silently.

Answer (score 1):

From [linux/i386/syscall.S](http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/07439d8df31d7fefe82ff127a1690193a34e9060/libc/sysdeps/linux/i386/syscall.S): The function number should be placed in %eax and any arguments in the following registers in order: %ebx, %ecx, %edx, %esi, %edi, and %ebp.

Which is why the last `movl %eax,0` in the code should be changed to `movl %ebx, 0`.

Comment: NP. Added the link to where I looked up which register it was supposed to be.